# What events triggers actions on Spring BeanFactory?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications

I have not been able to find much documentation on what sort of events can cause the BeanFactory to be recycled/cleared.

This is my scenario:

1. I have created a set of beans at runtime.
2. I am able to use the beans created at runtime with no problem.
3. I can "re-create" an existing bean which overrides the existing bean. By calling the following code:

   ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()).registerBeanDefinition("existingBean", builder.getBeanDefinition());

The answer I am looking for is a set of events that can cause the beans that I have created at run time to be cleared or recycled.

For example I know this:

1. On Container shutdown my beans will be destroyed.
2. On Container restart my beans will be destroyed.
3. ...
4. ...
   What are the other events?

More info..
Running JDK 1.8 with Tomcat 7.
Spring 4.5

I can see my beans by debugging in this manner:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
beanFactory.getBean("someBean");
```

If I inspect beanFactory object -> beanDefinitionMap -> table.
Then I can see all the beans created within the context of my web application.
I am trying to determine if there may be other scenarios that I am not aware of, that could lead my beans to dissapear over some point in time.

Comment: What do you mean by "creating" and "re-creating" a bean. Post the bean definition and the relevant code.

Comment: The code is not need to answer the question... By "re-create" the bean I mean registerBeanDefenition to an existing bean. Spring looks at the existing bean and it simply reinstantiates the bean. I can see the updated bean and I can see log indicating an existing bean definition is being over written. I will update my question with that bit of code if its necessary to answer my question.